# how to insert data to mysql and what does exception means?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am using the following code to insert data to MySql, but when I run the program and click the save button it gives me an error. I think I have no wrong spelled in my column but I don't know why it is not working? Please help me I'm stuck on this

```
Private Sub btnsavetreatment_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsavetreatment.Click
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=rico;database=god;"


    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        COMMAND.CommandText = "insert into god.treatmentrecord (Treatment_ID,Transaction_Date,ToothNo,Procedure,AmountCharge,AmountPaid,Balance) values (@treatmentid,@transactiondate,@toothno,@procedure,@amountcharged,@amountpaid,@balance)"
        COMMAND.Connection = MysqlConn
        COMMAND.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@treatmentid", txttreatmentid.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transactiondate", dtptransactiondate.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toothno", txttoothno.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@procedure", txtprocedure.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amountcharged", txtcharged.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amountpaid", txtamountpaid.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", txtbalance.Text)


        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Then this is the exception message**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'Procedure,AmountCharged,AmountPaid,Balance) values ('1','Wednesday,3 October 201' at line 1

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you use "god.treatmentrecord" instead of "treatmentrecord"? SQL may throw an error if it does not find the schema "god". Typically, we use "dbo" as in "dbo.treatmentrecord" or simply without the schema prefix, in which case it will be "treatmentrecord" only.